# UITableViewCell選択時の背景色の変化を徐々に変化(アニメーション)させる方法

Tags: ios, uitableview

UITableViewCellは通常タップされると即時に背景色の適用が行われてしまいます。
背景色が徐々に変化していくとUXが向上できると思います。

しかし、ネットで探しても背景色を変更する方法の記述はありますがアニメーションさせる方法は見つかりませんでした。
方法ご存知の方いましたら教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewCellのサブクラスでオーバーライド

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

  [super setSelected: selected animated: YES];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {

  [super setHighlighted: highlighted animated: YES];
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。試してみた所確かにアニメーションされているようです。しかし、画面遷移のスピードに対してアニメーションが遅すぎてアニメーションの初めの方で画面遷移が完了してしまいます。アニメーションの時間も指定できるとなおいいです。でも参考になりました。ありがとうございます。